# CloseWindow() vs ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE)

Tags: winapi

Does anyone know the difference between those two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CloseWindow() calls ShowWindow() with SW_SHOWMINIMIZED if the window is not already minimized.

Like IsIconic() and IsZoomed(), CloseWindow() is one of the old school window manipulation functions.

Comment: Haha, wait a sec though... if `CloseWindow` is old-school, and `ShowWindow` is the newer version, then what about `SetWindowPlacement`? Does it also call `ShowWindow`?

Comment: Get/SetWindowPlacement are helper functions that you mostly use to save and restore your window position at application startup/shutdown, it makes sure the window is on-screen etc. MoveWindow is the old school version of SetWindowPos, not SetWindowPlacement...

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

> **CloseWindow**
> Minimizes (but does not destroy) the specified window.
>
> **ShowWindow** (**SW_MINIMIZE**)
> Minimizes the specified window and activates the
> next top-level window in the Z order.

My guess is **CloseWindow** doesn't activate next top-level window.